# Phrasal Word Chains

Tags: word, english

Find the missing words in the chain, where consecutive pairs of words must form a phrase. 
For example,

> **HOLY**
>   - - - -
>   - - - -
>  
>   **RUN**

has the solution

> **HOLY**
>  **WAR**
>  **TRIAL**
>  **RUN**

The puzzle is based on the game show [Chain Reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_Reaction_(game_show)).
1.

> **BLACK**
>   - - - -
>   - - - -
>  
>   **PUZZLE**

2.

> **PUZZLE**
>   - - - -
>   - - - -
>  
>   **SANDWICH**

3.

> **STACK**
>  
>    - - - -
>    - - - -
>    **DUE** 
>    - - - -
>    - - - -
>    **SHIFT**
>    - - - -
>    - - - -
>  
>    - - - -
>   **EXCHANGE**

Comment: Is this based on British English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solutions:

> BLACK
>  MAGIC
>  WORD
>  PUZZLE

and

> PUZZLE
>  BOOK
>  CLUB
>  SANDWICH

and

> STACK
>  TRACE
>  AMOUNT
>  DUE
>  DATE
>  NIGHT
>  SHIFT
>  GROUND
>  BEEF
>  STOCK
>  EXCHANGE

Comment: The 2nd puzzle is correct and the 3rd has the correct words DATE and STOCK. Also the word GROUND was correct before you edited it.

Comment: Now it's all correct with the exception of EXCHANGE and VALUE. I should say the word after STACK was probably ill-chosen because it's not a general knowledge term, but computer science specific.

Comment: TRACE is right. Good guess with OVER but overdue is one word.

Comment: @DaniilAgashiyev 'back' instead of 'over'?

Comment: @manshu nope, not it.

Comment: @DaniilAgashiyev is ZERO wrong as well?

Comment: @Will, ZERO is wrong. Clue: Starts with 'A'.

Comment: Good job, puzzles 2 and 3 are solved.

Comment: @DaniilAgashiyev How's my new guess at the first one?

Comment: Yup, you got it!

Comment: "Shift ground" is certainly...interesting